# php image upload replace old picture

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to upload an image, to replace an old image. It says the image exists true and my unlink function false, also it says that the image is writeable. Some onw know where my error is ?

```
if (is_writable($_FILES["Bild"]["tmp_name"])) {
            echo 'The file is writable';
        } else {
            echo 'The file is not writable';
        }

        //altes Bild löschen
        //unlink("uploads/artikel/".$name.".jpg");
        echo "Name of File: " . $name;
        //Prüfen ob File exists
        echo"File existiert: " . var_dump(file_exists("/uploads/artikel/".$name.".jpg"));

        //Test
        echo "Löschen Status: " . var_dump(unlink(realpath("/uploads/artikel/".$name.".jpg")));



        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Bild"]["tmp_name"], "/uploads/artikel/" . $name . ".jpg")) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["Bild"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
```

Comment: what does `var_dump(realpath("/uploads/artikel/".$name.".jpg"));` return?

Comment: try this if(file_exists("/uploads/artikel/$name.jpg")) unlink("/uploads/artikel/$name.jpg"); before move_uploaded_file

Comment: var_dump(realpath("/uploads/artikel/".$name.".jpg")); returns bool(false)

Comment: It is because you give absolute destination path starting with /, which, MOST likely won’t exist. Also make sure that destination directory exists as moving the file to it won’t create it for you.

Comment: i changed it to ./uploads/artikel/

Comment: somehow on my localhost it works, but not on my "real" server, but it says it is writeable

Comment: why not giving it a random hash and store that hash in db with real file name?